# Associating keys to buttons on a Windows Form

Tags: c#, winforms

I have to write a method on C# that associates a certain key (from the keyboard) to a specific button. For example, if I press <kbd>A</kbd>, the button that I created on a form application should appear like it is being pressed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.KeyPreview = true;
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("Ctrl-F was Pressed.");
    }
    protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)
    {
        if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F))
        {
            button1.PerformClick();
        }
        return base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData);
    }
}
```

Note: To simulate click animation, make the Click event look like this:

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
        System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("foo");
        button1.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Standard;
    }
```

It's not perfect, but it works.

Comment: without the messagebox (at least something to break there) the animation doesn't work. In case of small processing nothing change.

Comment: I would imagine you'd have to hook the keydown and keyup events.

Comment: Probably or something with timer... idk it was just a remark. Nothing so important.